Refresh view after array changes in *ngFor or @for with pipes
If I use array in my template:
<div *ngFor="let project of projectsList | searchBy: ['name']:searchValue; index as i">
...

or
@for (project of projectsList | searchBy : ['name'] : searchValue; track project; let i = $index; ) {
  <div > 
  ...
}

with pipe
@Pipe({
    name: 'searchBy',
})
export class SearchByPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform<T>(value: T[], columnKeys: string[], term: string): T[] { 
        ...
    }
    ...
}

Then in Typescript code, after some action, I add element to array:
projectsList.push(newProject)

Nothing changes - the view is not updated (I do not see the new element on the project list). Why and how to fix it?

This is because you have still same array (the "pointer" projectsListto array not changes). Also, you use pure pipe (which is default in angular) which means that it will trigger only if input objects (parameters - here "pointer" to array projectsList) changes. But it will not trigger if only input object interior/structure chagnes but we operate still on same object.
If you want to still work on same object (array) and not change pipe to inpure (e.g. because is used in many places in your code) - then you can use following solution:
Add extra optional parameter forceUpdate to your pipe:
transform<T>(value: T[], columnKeys: string[], term: string, forceUpdate?: any): T[] 

then in template you can force refresch by use this new parameter with array.length (which will changes after add or delete some item from your array)
@for (project of projectsRoles | searchBy : ['name'] : searchValue : projectsRoles.length; track project; let i = $index; ) {
  <div > 
  ...
}

Now, because pipe parameter forceUpdate change value when array length changes, then angular will trigger pipe and refresch view.

nice! I am going to use this in future!
